# Transmit android sensors to pc server

Tags: android, python, sockets, server

I am working on a project that gives notifications to a web application when some phone sensors change their values rapidly. I am new to android and even though I know how to get the sensors values in my phone, I'm not sure how to transmit them to my pc server. I will look into sockets for network/bluetooth transmitting, but is there any way to send it via the internet ?

Basically, I want my application to work like this: I connect to my android application on phone, I shake the phone a bit and then on my web application on pc I get some notifications. I was looking around and I saw working with a python server?

How should I proceed here? Which method should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTTP/HTTPS on the Android Client to send to your server.  As that will be the easiest to program and most reliably way to get data off the phone regardless of network type.  See [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for details.  Just do a POST with your data to the web address.

If you don't want to just construct a simple PHP, ASPX, or other web service on top of a readily available HTTP server, then you can use a variety of HTTP server modules for Python.  [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) for example.

Comment: Thanks for your response